# For all times or for all ages?

Tags: phrase-choice

In Russian where is a fixed phrase *"для всех времен"* it can be translated as  *"for all time"*, *"for all times"* but actually it describes that something has a timeless value. It seems to me, that this word-by-word translation is not enough definitive, and does not use in English that meaning. So, I thought about *"for all ages"*. It looks like original phrase, but when I googled it, I found that it uses in general in meaning *"Suits for all ages"*...

It seems to me that *"for all times"* it more suitable variant. But maybe 
I miss something?

Comment: Your answer is in your question ;) "Timeless"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a period of time can be called "an age", as in *the stone age*, in the context you give "age" seems more specifically like you are talking about the individual ages of people.

If you are trying to say that an item or a thing is appealing to people of all different ages or age-groups then I would prefer something like:

> Suitable for all ages.

But if you are trying to say that something will last for a long time or appeal to people of future generations then I would personally use the word "*timeless*" or "*enduring*". Your suggestion of "for all times" is not a recognisable phrase and rather ambiguous.

You could say:

> This has timeless value.

or

> This has enduring appeal.